# How to compute the $((1-\alpha )\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of the null distribution in R

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

For fixed $n$ and arbitrarily preselected values $\mu$ and $\sigma$,

First, I generated a random sample of size $n$ from $N(\mu ,\sigma)$, say $x_1 ,x_2 ,\ldots ,x_n$;

Second, I arranged the obtained sample from the smallest to the largest.

Next, I estimtated $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}$ and $S=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i -\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$, respectively.

Then, I computed the statistic $\delta=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|z_i -\frac{i}{n}|}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\max (z_i ,\frac{i}{n})}$.

Finally, I repeated previous steps 25 times to get the set $\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 ,\ldots ,\delta_{25}\}$I assume $z_i =\phi (\frac{x_i -\bar{x}}{S})$, the CDF of the standard Normal distribution with $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}$ and $S=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i -\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$.

My code is as follows:

```
n=10
mu=100
sigma=10
D=c()
for(j in 1:25){
x=rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
x=x[order(x)]
S=sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / (n - 1))
z = c()
for(i in 1:n){
 z[i] = dnorm((x[i]-mean(x))/S,0,1)
}
num = 0 
for(i in 1:n){
 num = num + abs(z[i]-i/n)
}
den = 0
for(i in 1:n){
 den = den + max(z[i],i/n)
}
D[j]=delta = num/den
}
```

Here I'm using the normal test of the sample which is equivalent to test the null hypothesis $H_0 :F_0 =Normal(\mu ,\sigma)$, where the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown.

My question is that: How can I compute the $\delta_{\alpha ,n}$, $((1-\alpha )\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of the null distribution of $\delta$ at $n$ that satisfies $P(\delta >\delta_{\alpha ,n}|H_0 )=\alpha$ in R program.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which test do you want to do and what are exactly your questions?

Comment: @AbdoulHaki Thanks for the comment. I've edited the question.

Comment: I moved what the problem is.. to the top. If you approve it

Comment: @AlBrown sorry, my question is different. Thanks any way.

Comment: What computer programming language do you use to write your code?

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu In R language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you doing is basically a Monte Carlo Estimate of a specific quantile $\delta_{\alpha ,n}$ so that, $P(\delta >\delta_{\alpha ,n}|H_0)=\alpha.$

Your method would be like this:

- Let $F$ be the distribution of $\delta$ under the null distribution.
- Simulate random sample $\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3,\cdots,\delta_N$ from $F$; $\delta_i\sim F \ \forall i$
- Compute the empirical distribution corresponding to them:
  $$F_N(x)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{I}_{\delta_i\le x} \left(\stackrel{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}F(x)\right)$$
- So your estimated quantile would be:
  $$F_N^{-1}(\alpha)$$ for a **large enough N**
- This quantile $F_N^{-1}(\alpha)$ can be approximated by the ["almost sure left inverse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) $$\inf\{x\,|\, F_N(x)\geq \alpha\}$$

Your code is almost okay, you have to finally calculate `sort(D)[length(D)*alpha]`. Also, take a much larger value of $N$ than just 25.

So, finally, in `R`, your program would be (taking a larger value of N, not 25):

```
n=10
mu=100
sigma=10
N=1000
alpha=0.05     # Or your favorite value

D=array(0, dim=N)
for(j in 1:N){
    x=rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
    x=x[order(x)]       ## or use sort(x)

    # S=sd(x)           ## sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / (n - 1))
    # z = c()
    # for(i in 1:n){
    #     z[i] = dnorm((x[i]-mean(x))/S,0,1)
    # }
    z=dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))  # R can do it at once

    # num=0
    # for(i in 1:n){
    #     num = num + abs(z[i]-i/n)
    # }
    num = sum( abs(z - seq(1,n)/n ) ) 

    # den = 0
    # for(i in 1:n){
    #     den = den + max(z[i],i/n)
    # }
    den = sum( pmax(z, seq(1,n)/n) )

    D[j]=num/den
}
sort(D)[N*alpha]
```

I have commented on some parts of your codes and compacted them.

Comment: Dear Subrata Pal, thank you very very much for your good information about Monte Carlo Estimate, for the link, for your nice hints and great comments concerning my code. I appreciate you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: Dear Subrata Pal, I have more one question related to above problem. Could you please tell me which code in R we can use to compute the $((1-\alpha)\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of other distributions, like Beta distribution? For example, I want to the approximate the $((1-\alpha)\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of the null distribution by the $((1-\alpha)\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of Beta distribution with specific parameters $p(n)$ and q(n)$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `qbeta` for that case with the named distribution. 
In general, use the format `q<distribution name>` to find the quantiles. (e.g., qnorm, qgamma, qchisq)
The common prefix naming convention is: `p` for probability, `q` for quantile, `d` for density, `r` for random number generation from the corresponding distribution. 

For example, `qbeta(alpha, shape1, shape2)` would give you corresponding value. To know more, look at `?qbeta` and also `?Distributions`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Dear @SubrataPal , I am very sorry to bother you again. I've added two pictures in the question, one explains the code I need and another one shows the results of that code (I have to obtain). Unfortunately, The results of my code (in your answer) and  the results of the table are not the same. Is there something wrong here?